# order by sql data using condtions (case) based on derived columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select, sql-order-by

I want to put a condtion to sort SQL data based on the value of derived columns as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sp.ID
    , sp.Status
    , sp.Rank
    , sp.Price
    , sp.SalePrice
    , sp.Width
    , sp.Height
    , sp.QOH
    , (sp.SalePrice*sp.QOH) As 'sp.Value'
    , (sp.Price*sp.QOH) As 'sp.StandardValue'
FROM table 
WHERE -- Conditions
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN 'sp.SalePrice' > 0 THEN 'sp.Value'  END DESC,
  CASE WHEN 'sp.SalePrice' = 0 THEN 'sp.StandardValue'  END DESC
```

Gves this error:

> Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

if i try

```
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN sp.SalePrice > 0 THEN (sp.SalePrice*sp.QOH) As "sp.Value"  END DESC,
  CASE WHEN sp.SalePrice = 0 THEN (sp.Price*sp.QOH) As sp.StandardValue" END DESC
```

Gives error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'As'.

it starts giving the same select distinct error if i try to remove aliases * as from order by cluase & only leave the multiplication part

Comment: Are there any subqueries in your `WHERE` conditions? I don't see a `DISTINCT`. Did you perhaps include a `DISTINCT` at some point and forget to include it in your question above?

Comment: i forgot to add DISTINCT  to code above, done that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second example is closest as it specifies the columns correctly.  However, you cannot alias columns in the order by.  This would work:

```
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN sp.SalePrice > 0 THEN sp.SalePrice*sp.QOH END DESC,
  CASE WHEN sp.SalePrice = 0 THEN sp.Price*sp.QOH END DESC
```

Or alternatively just use the alias you defined in the result set:

```
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN sp.SalePrice > 0 THEN [sp.Value] END DESC,
  CASE WHEN sp.SalePrice = 0 THEN [sp.StandardValue] END DESC
```

Note the brackets [].... this is required to define the column name as you used a dotted name in the alias... otherwise sp.Value would be considered to be the Value column in the sp table.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to add a bunch of suggestions about general conventions below, but as to the main problem consider what you're trying to do with this example:

My_Table:

```
id    value
1     1
2     2
3     1
```

Now, try to show distinct `value` ordering by id. Which should it be?

```
value
1
2
```

or

```
value
2
1
```

So, you're asking SQL Server to do something that may be impossible or at least unclear.

Now, as to conventions... Maybe some of this is just how you've posted here, but I would make the following suggestions for your code:

Avoid using reserved and SQL language words for names. This would include `table`, `rank`, and `status`.

Avoid using special characters in names. This would include `sp.value`. Sure, you can do it with a quoted identifier, but some front-ends, etc. might not support them even if SQL does and you don't really buy anything by using them in most cases.

Use the quoted identifier when you have to quote names. If you absolutely must violate one of the above two suggestions, use the standard quoted identifiers for SQL Server, which are `[` and `]`. If you want to quote aliases, use these as well (and you shouldn't have to typically quote aliases BTW). This helps to avoid the problem that Mark B points out.

Your `CASE` statement can be better written as one ordering column. Also, you should include an ELSE in most cases to avoid unhandled conditions. This may not be needed here as long as you can't have NULLs or negative values in any of the involved columns.

```
CASE
    WHEN sp.SalePrice > 0 THEN (sp.SalePrice*sp.QOH)
    WHEN sp.SalePrice = 0 THEN (sp.Price*sp.QOH)
END
```

I would personally avoid using the table alias (which it looks like you accidentally left out of your query) as part of your column aliases. It makes it much more confusing IMO because it makes it look like that aliased column is actually a column in the table.

Comment: but assuming this value is a alias

Comment: Why should it be 2, 1? There is a value with an `id` of 1, so why wouldn't that one come first? Do you see how the `DISTINCT` makes it so that you might end up ordering by a column which might have multiple values associated with each row that is actually being displayed?

Comment: Tom, thanks for detailed answer, key words like `table` are only being used for demonstration purposes. the case mentioned by you exactly gives an error `incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'` even if i put `CASE sp.SalePrice` the error presists

Comment: Sorry... I forgot that you can't use aliases in an `ORDER BY`. I'll correct that code. You weren't getting the error before because SQL was treating 'sp.Value' as the actual string 'sp.value'.

Comment: @TomH. - You **can** use aliases in `ORDER BY`

Comment: Hmmm... you're right Martin. I've changed only the alias and the query works ok here, but when I try to use the alias it's giving an unknown column error. When I pull the column out of the `CASE` statement it works as well. Very odd.

Comment: @TomH - Ah right. Didn't notice that it was in a `CASE` (but didn't realize that would be treated differently anyway...)

Answer (score 1):

using `'` around field names turns them into strings. Either remove the quotes entirely, or use `"` instead.

Comment: replacing `'` with `"sp.Value"`results in order by clause giving an error Msg 207, 
Invalid column name

Comment: You can't use aliases in order/where clauses in SQL server. You have to replicate the full derivation function, so it'd be `ORDER BY ... THEN sp.SalePrice*sp.QOH ... `

Comment: i have updated the question to include your suggestion, it also gives an error

Comment: You can use aliases in `ORDER BY` as logically this is processed after `SELECT`